# How do I Instantiate a player prefab

Tags: prefabs

I turned my player into a prefab for a endless runner game but how would i instatiate it so that the player is in the scene when the game starts without it currertly being on a seprate platform that the player then ends up jumping from to get onto the road

Comment: I'm sorry, but I read this question several times and have still no idea what the actual problem is. Can you please rewrite it as a series of complete, grammatically correct sentences with punctuation? Also keep in mind that we can not see your project or your code. "Platform" and "road" are abstract concepts that only exist in your game. If you want others to understand what you mean, you have to describe them using the technical terms of the things you represent them with.

Comment: @Philipp  im dyslexic so dont tell me to write like im in school i can not do that .. and secondaly i dont have any code to show .. its also pretty simple all i want to know is how to INSTANSIATE my player and dont tell me to rewrite it

Comment: I am sorry that you are dyslexic, but that does not change the fact that I can simply not understand what you write. I would like to help you, but I can not help you when you can not describe the problem in a way that I can understand it.

Comment: @Philipp ALL I WANT TO KNOW IS HOW DO I INSTANIATE MY PLAYER READ THE TITLE

Comment: @Philipp sorry didnt mean in caps

Comment: @Philipp my issue is that i dont know how to instaiate my player prefab into my game

Answer (score 0):

You would just drag the prefab into the editor. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361621/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-prefab-asset-in-unity

Instantiation at runtime seems also given in the docs here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

```
public class InstantiationExample : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Reference to the Prefab. Drag a Prefab into this field in the Inspector.
    public GameObject myPrefab;

    // This script will simply instantiate the Prefab when the game starts.
    void Start()
    {
        // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
        Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is in the editor but doesnt appear on the end;ess runner bit only the platform o had created temporailry

Comment: This would work for the initial placement, but since it is for an endless runner, OP will have the same problem when coins, power ups, barricades or respawn has to be handled. The answer could be improved if you explain as well how to instantiate at runtime via code (or link to one of the many answers that handle that already)

Comment: @charlie the green tick means, the answer solved your problem and no further answers are really expected (since people see it as solved).

Comment: @charlie , have linked to the docs, hope that helps